# jquery remove element from the clone

Tags: jquery, clone

```
$('div ul li a')
   .live('click', function() {
      $('div').clone().insertBefore('div:first');
      $(this).parents('div').find('ul li a:last').remove();
   });
```

I am trying to make it so that every time I click on a link, the cloned div will have a link removed from it until there is only 1 link left.

Comment: please add your html structure also to get an idea of what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

Is this you want to do?

**JS**

```
$('div a').live('click', function () {
  var cloneDiv = $('div:first').clone();
  cloneDiv.find('li:last').remove();
  cloneDiv.insertBefore('div:first');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Try the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/vE65d/1/)